# GTK Setting Default Printer

Tags: c, linux, printing, gtk3, gnome

Among the GTK3 print functions is this one, to confirm the current default printer:

```
gtk_printer_is_default ()
```

However, this is only useful after a call to this enumerating function:

```
gtk_enumerate_printers ()
```

Are there any functions to ***GET*** and ***SET*** the default printer directly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is up to you set in your application the default
printer, the API has not the effort to provide the GETs or SETs.
Your application should be something like this:

```
static gboolean
get_default_printer(GtkPrinter *printer, gpointer data)
{
        gboolean ret = gtk_printer_is_default(printer);
        if (ret)
                set_default_printer = printer;

        return ret;
}
```

Comment: Yes; that would get and record the default printer, but not ***set another printer*** as default. How would we set one of the ***other enumerated printers*** as the default printer?

Comment: sorry if I am wrong but this API doesn't work this way, you should look for CUPS.